# If not Check then Add to Cash

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I ran the below code that Adnan helped me out with last night (Thanks very much Adnan).

Basically, the code checks if the amount being entered is check. If it is check, insert the check value into chckval.

If it is cash insert the cash value into cashval.

So far, it is half working. It inserts the check into the check fieldname and inserts 0 into cash fieldname. This is is working great.

What is not working is inserting cash into cash fieldname if the money is cash.

It inserts the cash into cash fieldname as it should BUT it also inserts the same amount into check fieldname. This is not good.

If it is cash and it is inserted into cash fieldname, I want check value to be 0.

Here is the latest code and thanks again.

```
For x = 1 To 5 Step 1
    dedval = Gridview1.FindControl("ded" & CStr(x))
    chckval = Gridview1.FindControl("chck" & CStr(x))
    chcknumval = Gridview1.FindControl("chcknum" & CStr(x))
    checkboxval = Gridview1.FindControl("chckBox" & CStr(x))
    onetimeval = Gridview1.FindControl("onetime" & CStr(x))
    multival = Gridview1.FindControl("multi" & CStr(x))
    If chckval.Text <> "" And Not checkboxval.Checked Then
        cashval = DirectCast(Gridview1.FindControl("chck" & CStr(x)), TextBox).Text
    Else
        chckval = Gridview1.FindControl("chck" & CStr(x))
    End If
    If dedval.Text <> "-1" And donatechoice.SelectedItem.Value <> "No" Then
        sql += "INSERT INTO employee_ded_amts (employee_id, charity_code, check_amt, chcknum, one_time, bi_weekly, cash, donate_choice, date_stamp) "
        sql += "VALUES ('" & Replace(employee_idLabel.Text, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(dedval.SelectedValue, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(chckval.Text, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(chcknumval.Text, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(onetimeval.Text, "'", "''") & "','" & multival.Text & "','" & Replace(cashval, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(donatechoice.SelectedItem.Value, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(datestamp, "'", "''") & "');"
    End If
    If donatechoice.SelectedItem.Value = "No" Then
        x = 6
        sql += "INSERT INTO employee_ded_amts (employee_id, charity_code, check_amt, chcknum, one_time, bi_weekly, cash, donate_choice, date_stamp) "
        sql += "VALUES ('" & Replace(employee_idLabel.Text, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(dedval.SelectedValue, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(chckval.Text, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(chcknumval.Text, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(onetimeval.Text, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(multival.Text, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(cashval, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(donatechoice.SelectedItem.Value, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(datestamp, "'", "''") & "');"
    End If
Next
```

I think there is some issue with the

```
IF chckval.Text <> "" And Not checkboxval.Checked Then
```

statment

Comment: FYI, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/. Also, FYI, this is not a forum.

Comment: Maybe this should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Your code looks like it is open to SQL injection attacks. You should look at parameterizing your sql statments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

===========

## Update

Try changing this line as follows if cashval is a string type,

```
 cashval = DirectCast(fvEmp.FindControl("chck" & CStr(x)),TextBox).Text;
```

Kenny thing I figured out is FindControl returns Control Type which need to be converted into TextBox type if it is a TextBox control and then you can use its Text property to get the string. I edited it above. Try it now.

In C# it will be done like this.

```
 string cashval = ((TextBox)(fvEmp.FindControl("whatever control name"))).Text;
```

==============

## New UPDATE

```
chckval = Gridview1.FindControl("chck" & CStr(x))
```

Kenny now this third line is causing the problem I believe. Try removing this second line from For loop. But when you remove this second line you also will need to assign some value to your chckval TextBox type variable as it can not be null when it is used in query. May be you can assign new empty TextBox

Or

You can also make checkval String like you made cashval variable string this will simplify it.

But whatever value you assign to checkval assign it in this IF statement.

```
    If chckval.Text <> "" And Not checkboxval.Checked Then
     cashval = DirectCast(Gridview1.FindControl("chck" & CStr(x)), TextBox).Text
     < SET SOME VALUE FOR chckval here ... which is default value which will be used in SQL server> 
      Else
      chckval = Gridview1.FindControl("chck" & CStr(x))
```

Comment: Thank you Adnan, That was inte,ntional for 2 reasons. One, I got this when I had it as cashval.text Value of type 'System.Web.UI.Control' cannot be converted to 'String'. But also notice chckval doesn't have/ doesn't need .text

Comment: Sorry, my fault. It should be Dim cashval As String since it doesn't exist in the markup.

Comment: It is still the same line and it is still saying "Value of type 'System.Web.UI.Control' cannot be converted to 'String'." Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Error says, TextBox is a type and cannot be used as an expression. You said you are not good with vb. If you are good with c# and you can assist with that language, pls do and I will try to convert it. Thank you very much again.

Comment: Kenny thing I figured out is FindControl returns Control Type which need to be converted into TextBox type if it is a TextBox control and then you can use its Text property to get the string. I edited it above. Try it now.

Comment: Thankyou very much Adan. The error is gone. I am going to be testing tomorrow since it is after mid night here. I am grateful, very much so for your assistance.

Comment: I just ran this code this morning. It works but not perfectly. It amount is cash, it inserts it into cashval. The problem is that it inserts it into chckval. Can someone please tell me what to adjust? Thanks alot

Comment: Kenny now it is a problem with the query itself. So modify your original question above to show what is happening. I have to run out and will be back in 2 hours then I will try to modify the query but make sure to update main question above. Not everyone is going to read comments.

Comment: chckval = Gridview1.FindControl("chck" & CStr(x))     Kenny now this third line is causing the problem I believe. Try removing this third line from For loop.

Comment: I am glad its working for you now. I never asked question on Stackoverflow so don't know for sure, but I think checkmark should show up if you hover your mouse around up down arrows of answer.